Property of a smooth function is true for almost every function
Consider a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. We further assume $0$ is a regular value of $f$, thus $X=f^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth submanifold of dimension $n-1$. Consider the following function $g_f: X\to S^{n-1}$ defined by $$x\mapsto g_f(x)=\dfrac{df(x)}{\lVert df(x)\rVert}$$ This is also known as the Gauss map. Call this function $f$ "nice" if the Gauss map $g_f$ is a diffeomorphism. My question is, is this property generic? That is, given any smooth function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, and
$\epsilon>0$ is there a "nice" smooth function $\tilde{h}$, such that $$\lVert h-\tilde{h}\rVert_\infty <\epsilon?$$
My guess is it is true, because being a diffeomorphism seems to me an open condition, but I don't know how to rigorously prove it. Any suggestions would be welcome.

I kind of doubt that having a fiber diffeomorphic to a sphere is a generic property of smooth maps. Like the fiber at zero could be a genus 1 curve or something like that, and my feeling (coming from AG intuition) is that the genus does not jump with perturbations. Perhaps if you assume the starting function is nice, any small perturbation will be as well.

A diffeomorphism of spheres can be equivalently described as a local diffeomorphism that induces an isomorphism of top-degree cohomology groups.  Both properties are stable under small perturbations.

Hi Dmitri, do you know a more elementary way to do this problem? If you're willing to elaborate a bit more on your answer, i.e. why such a description indeed is enough, and why the property of being an isomorphism of top degree cohomology is stable under perturbations? Also this may be a stupid question, but when you say diffeomorphism of spheres, aren't you implicitly assuming that $X$ is already a sphere? I feel showing a smooth map $f:X\to S^{n-1}$ being diffeomorphism and $f:S^{n-1}\to S^{n-1}$ being diffeomorphism are different problems.
